# WIX Bootstrapper - Add combo box

Tags: wix, bootstrapper, burn, wixstdba

How do I add a combo box to a WiX Bootstrapper?

I use `HyperlinkLargeTheme.xml` and have tried to add a combo box to the install page.
It appears on the dialog, but I don't know how to add values to it.

```
<Page Name="Install">        
      <Text Name="InstallLanguge" X="20" Y="200" Width="100" Height="17" FontId="3" DisablePrefix="yes" HideWhenDisabled="yes">Select Language</Text>

      <Combobox X="130" Y="200" Width="150" Height="17" FontId="3" Name="Language">
        <ListItem Text="English" Value="eng" />
        <ListItem Text="Japanese" Value="jp" />
        <ListItem Text="Chinese" Value="cn" />
      </Combobox>

      <Button Name="InstallButton" X="-91" Y="-11" Width="75" Height="23" TabStop="yes" FontId="0">#(loc.InstallInstallButton)</Button>
</Page>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ComboBox is not supported. You need a custom BootstrapperApplication to do that.
Some how you can add them to the dialog but you wont able to populate em.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is some code for combo-boxes in WiX 3.11, but it's incomplete, and is not usable in standard bootstrapper application. However it works actually, so I've implemented the missing part for myself, almost exactly as described in your post. See corresponding [ticket](https://github.com/wixtoolset/issues/issues/5934) and [fork](https://github.com/denis-gz/wix3). There is no official build yet, and probably won't be, but I can share my own build [here](https://github.com/denis-gz/wix3/releases/tag/3.11.19010.3729). It didn't compile clean (CHM docs compiled with warnings), it's unsigned, and didn't pass most of the tests (since test suite appears to be broken and not maintained for a while). However it does work for me, and is used in a real project. It has some additional fixes as well.